# Not able to send the value of facebook email to the server using facebook login in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to do a facebook login in my application but i am not able to send the value of facebook email to the app server. when i am debugging the app inside onCompleted i can see the facebook email but when i am passing that value it shows null.fb_login is an ImageButton, its not a facebooklogin button.

here is my Code :-

```
fb_login.setOnClickListener(v -> {


            if (internetDetector.hasConnectivity()) {

                flag = 1;



                onFblogin();


            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



        });
```

Below is onfbLogin method in which i am making a graph request and trying to save the email , id , name into the variables which are global.

```
 private void onFblogin()  {
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        // Set permissions
       fbLoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList( "email",  "public_profile"));

        fbLoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                        System.out.println("Success");
                       GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                                            // handle error
                                            System.out.println("ERROR");
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("Success");
                                            try {

                                                String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
                                                System.out.println("JSON Result"+jsonresult);

                                              facebookName = json.getString("name");
                                              facebookEmail = json.getString("email");
                                              facebookid = json.getString("id");



                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                });

                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("facebook Login","On cancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.d("facebook Login",error.toString());
                    }
                });


        return;
    }
```

after this i am having onActivityResult method.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(completedTask);
        }
        else {

            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                   postDataToServer();

        }

    }
```

Inside the  postDataToServer() method i am trying to get the values of facebookEmail but i am getting null over there. Maybe i am doing it in a wrong manner. Please guide me so i can make changes and get the values of variables.

Comment: can you show code inside postDataToServer()?

Comment: @nik please check the updated question.

Comment: call postToDataServer Method below 
facebookName = json.getString("name");
facebookEmail = json.getString("email");
facebookid = json.getString("id");

---------here-------------

Comment: @nik thank you nik ...it worked out ...if you find this question can help others as it has complete code for custom facebook login .then please upvote the question.

Comment: the problem was that when you request for facebook email and profile  the callbackManager.OnActivityResult gets called first then on succes gets called thats why you were getting null because the values wasnt able to intialize.

Comment: okay ...thank you for the information.